# Dataproc Cluster Spark job submission fails in GPU clusters after restarting master VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I followed the tutorial on https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/gpus and created a single-node n1-standard-16 Dataproc cluster (base image is: 1.5.35-debian10) and attached Tesla T4 GPU. I installed NVIDIA drivers after creating the cluster and I was able to run my Spark jobs that run on GPU successfully.

However when I stop the master instance, start it again and submit a new Dataproc job, it fails with "Task was not acquired" after 5 minutes, and couldn't find any way to run jobs in the same cluster.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: After investigating hadoop-yarn logs at /var/log/hadoop-yarn folder as suggested by @Dagang, it seems that it's related to YARN Node Manager. Node manager fails with the following messages.

Edit2: The main failure reason is "Unexpected: Cannot create yarn cgroup Subsystem:devices Mount points:/proc/mounts User:yarn Path:/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/yarn". As suggested in [Hadoop official website](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications/hadoop-yarn-submarine/TestAndTroubleshooting.html):, the following lines need to run in the installation script:

```
chown :yarn -R /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
chmod g+rwx -R /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct

chown :yarn -R /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
chmod g+rwx -R /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
```

However these commands already exist in [install_gpu_drivers.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/blob/HEAD/gpu/install_gpu_driver.sh)

Complete error log:

```
Specified path is a directory, use nvidia-smi under the directory, updated path-to-executable
:/usr/bin/nvidia-smi
Trying to discover GPU information ...
=== Gpus in the system ===
        Driver Version:460.73.01
        ProductName=Tesla T4, MinorNumber=0, TotalMemory=15109MiB, Utilization=0.0%

CGroup controller already mounted at: /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
Initializing mounted controller devices at /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/yarn
Yarn control group does not exist. Creating /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/yarn
Failed to bootstrap configured resource subsystems!
Unexpected: Cannot create yarn cgroup Subsystem:devices Mount points:/proc/mounts User:yarn Path:/sys/fs/cgroup/de
vices/yarn 

        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.resources.CGroupsHandlerImpl.initializePreMountedCGroupController(CGroupsHandlerImpl.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.resources.CGroupsHandlerImpl.initializeCGroupController(CGroupsHandlerImpl.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.resources.gpu.GpuResourceHandlerImpl.bootstrap(GpuResourceHandlerImpl.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.resources.ResourceHandlerChain.bootstrap(ResourceHandlerChain.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:391)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:946)
2021-09-17 07:18:56,215 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container execu
tor
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:946)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bootstrap configured resource subsystems!
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:391)
        ... 3 more
2021-09-17 07:18:56,216 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:946)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bootstrap configured resource subsystems!
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:391)
        ... 3 more
2021-09-17 07:18:56,219 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

How to reproduce:
I use Google Dataproc Node.js Client library to create Dataproc clusters. Here is my configuration:

```
request: ClusterCreateInput = {
        projectId: 'my-project-id',
        region: 'europe-west-1',
        cluster: {
          projectId: 'my-project-id',
          clusterName: 'test-cluster',
          config: {
            configBucket: 'my-dataproc-log-bucket',
            gceClusterConfig: {
              zoneUri: 'europe-west-1-d',
              serviceAccountScopes: [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write',
              ],
            },
            masterConfig: {
              numInstances: 1,
              machineTypeUri: `n1-standard-16`,
              diskConfig: {
                bootDiskSizeGb: 100,
                bootDiskType: 'pd-standard',
                numLocalSsds: 0,
              },
              accelerators: [
                {
                  acceleratorTypeUri: 'nvidia-tesla-t4',
                  acceleratorCount: 1,
                },
              ],
              imageUri: '1.5.35-debian10',
            },
            softwareConfig: {
              properties: {
                'dataproc:dataproc.allow.zero.workers': true,
                'spark:spark.executor.instances': '1',
                'spark:spark.executor.cores': '16',
                'spark:spark.default.parallelism': '16',
                'spark:spark.executor.memory': `38000m`,
                'spark-env:ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT': '1',
                'spark:spark.executorEnv.LD_PRELOAD': 'libnvblas.so',
              },
            },
            initializationActions: [
              {
                executableFile: `gs://my-bucket-name/install_gpu_driver.sh`,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      }

const [clusterOperation] = await this.client.createCluster(request)
const [result] = await clusterOperation.promise()
```

After creating the cluster, submit a basic job. Stop and start the VM when the job is completed and re-submit a similar job. The cluster will not acquire this new job.

Comment: "Task was not acquired" indicates the Dataproc agent on the master node might not be functioning correctly. Try SSH into the master, check log at `/var/log/google-dataproc-agent*.log`, check status `systemctl status google-dataproc-agent` and try `sudo systemctl restart google-dataproc-agent`.

Comment: Also try restarting the master node again.

Comment: Thanks! The log file at /var/log/google-dataproc-agent0.log warns that "INFO: Only 0 out of 1 minimum required node managers running." 
systemctl status google-dataproc-agent > This gives that google-dataproc-agent is running. Aso neither restarting the google-dataproc-agent nor the master node doesn't help solve the issue.

Comment: The problem seems to be with YARN NodeManager, check logs at /var/log/haoop-yarn. Also check status with `systemctl status hadoop-yarn-nodemanager`.

Comment: Thanks! hadoop-yarn-node-manager fails at the initialization and I added logs to the question body.

Comment: Is this a single node cluster? Could you add your command to create the cluster? I can help reproduce.

Comment: Yes, @Dagang it's a single node cluster. I edited my post and added my cluster configuration. I use "1.5.35-debian10" as a base image. "install_gpu_driver.sh" hosted in my bucket is the exactly the same script published here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/blob/HEAD/gpu/install_gpu_driver.sh

Comment: GPU initialization action calls ```chmod a+rwx -R /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct``` and ```chmod 777 -R /sys/fs/cgroup/devices``` to assign 777 to these folders. However, when we stop the cluster and run it again, these folders get "dr-xr-xr-x" (ie 555) permissions. That seems to be the main issue here.

Comment: Dataproc init actions are executed only once for a VM, you might need GCE VM startup script in this case.

Comment: As far as I know, stopping a VM and starting it should keep everything intact on the boot disk. Do you know why this is not the case with folder permissions?

Comment: The dirs seem to be in-memory dirs, which lose permission changes after reboot.

Comment: Is there any way to define the VM start-up script while creating the dataproc cluster?

Comment: `--metadata startup-script="echo hello"` or `--metadata startup-script-url=<script-url>`

Comment: I'm using Google compute/dataproc nodejs client libs and I used `setMetadata` function to add my startup script which gives 777 to in-memory dirs again. This approach led the dataproc job to be acquired by YARN and it started. However, now I received "Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources" warning. "systemctl status hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager" returns that resource manager is active.